# Global variable reads inside tight loops in C

Tags: c, performance, stack, global-variables, global

Say I have a tight loop in C, within which I use the value of a global variable to do some arithmetics, e.g.

```
double c;
// ... initialize c somehow ...

double f(double*a, int n) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += a[i]*c;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

with `c` the global variable. Is `c` "read anew from global scope" in each loop iteration? After all, it could've been changed by some other thread executing some other function, right? Hence would the code be faster by taking a local (function stack) copy of `c` prior to the loop and only use this copy?

```
double f(double*a, int n) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  int i;
  double c_cp = c;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += a[i]*c_cp;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Though I haven't specified how `c` is initialized, let's assume it's done in some way such that the value is unknown at compile time. Also, `c` is really a constant throughout runtime, i.e. I as the programmer knows that its value won't change. Can I let the compiler in on this information, e.g. using `static double c` in the global scope? Does this change the `a[i]*c` vs. `a[i]*c_cp` question?

#### My own research

- Reading e.g. the "Global variables" section of [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6154/Writing-Efficient-C-and-C-Code-Optimization), it seems clear that taking a local copy of the global variable is the way to go. However, they want to update the value of the global variable, whereas I only ever want to read its value.
- Using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aGP59Y) I fail to notice any real difference in the assembly for both `c` vs. `c_cp` and `double c` vs. `static double c`.

Comment: Your first code can be [optimized to read `c` only once](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/861nqn).

Comment: @MikeCAT How does this differ from the godbolt link in my question (which obviously still leaves me confused)?

Comment: `c` “can be” changed by other threads, but it should not. The compiler is permitted to treat `c` as if it is not changed by other threads, per the rules in C 2018 5.1.2.4, so it is the programmer’s responsibility to ensure this does not happen. So, in the specific code you show, the compiler may load `c` once per function call. However, suppose your code contained an assignment such as `a[i] = …;`. Then the compiler could not know whether `a[i]` was the same as `c` (actually, this would only be defined for `i` equal to zero or possibly −1), so it would have to guard against this.

Answer (score 2):

Any decently smart compiler will optimize your code so it will behave as your second code snippet. Using `static` won't change much, but if you want to ensure read on each iteration then use `volatile`.

Great point there about changes from a different thread. Compiler will maintain integrity of your code as far as single-threaded execution goes. That means that it can reorder your code, skip something, add something -- as long as the end result is still the same.

With multiple threads it is **your job** to ensure that things still happen in a specific order, not just that the end result is right. The way to ensure that are memory barriers. It's a fun topic to read, but one that is best avoided unless you're an expert.

Comment: Ah, I see. So `volatile` does the exact opposite of what I want. And what I want is indeed the default behavior. Furthermore, the thread "issue" is not the compilers job to deal with, so it won't cause it to miss out on the optimization. I think I got it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Once everything translated to machine code, you will get no difference whatsoever. If c is global, any access to c will reference the address of c or most probably, in a tight loop c will be kept in a register, or in the worst case the L1 cache.

On a Linux machine you can easily generate the assembly and examine the resultant code.

You can also run benchmarks.

Comment: I *have* the assembly, see the godbolt link in the question. Can you explain how `c` can be kept in a register, when it's possible for some other thread to change the value, as mentioned in the question?

Comment: As stated by @TomoCeferin using volatile will ensure the latest value of c is used (assuming multi-threading). That said, I would simply pass c as a parameter. It's much cleaner and at the end is not much different than using c_cp = c which goes on the stack.

Comment: Generally I would agree. In my actual code I have hundreds of globals, which I really do not want to pass around (even collected into a `struct`) as it would lead to considerate clutter. Anyway, that's not the question.